# How to calculate detectable effect size in Python (statsmodels or other)

Tags: python, statistics, statsmodels, sampling

I have a different sort of question from my usual. It pertains to power and sample size calculations in Python (or Excel, whatever). In Python Statsmodels is useful for doing this. For example, the below code will output sample size provided alpha, power and effect size.

However, I want this equation solved for effect size. Meaning, I need to calculate maximum detectable effect size, provided a set alpha, power, and n.

If statsmodels can do it, I haven't figured out how. Alternatively I'd be happy to solve the equation, but I can't do it. Not sure if this kind of question fits here, but happy if anyone can help!

```
from statsmodels.stats.power import TTestIndPower

#parameters for the analysis 
effect_size = 0.2
alpha = 0.05 # significance level
power = 0.3

power_analysis = TTestIndPower()
sample_size = power_analysis.solve_power(effect_size = effect_size, 
                                         power = power, 
                                         alpha = alpha)

print('Required sample size: {0:.2f}'.format(sample_size))
```

Comment: add `nobs` as argument and use `effect_size=None`, then it will solve for effect size given the other 3 arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just numerically solve the equation for `effect_size` using e.g. [`root_scalar`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.root_scalar.html#scipy.optimize.root_scalar):

```
from statsmodels.stats.power import TTestIndPower
from scipy import optimize

sample_size = 100
alpha = 0.05
power = 0.3
power_analysis = TTestIndPower()

def f(effect_size):
    return power_analysis.solve_power(effect_size=effect_size, power=power, alpha = alpha) - sample_size

print('Maximum detectable effect size: {0:.2f}'.format(optimize.root_scalar(f, bracket=[0.01, 1.0]).root))
```

Result:

```
Maximum detectable effect size: 0.20
```

Comment: That uses double, nested root finding. Your `f` function has to solve for the sample size for each effect size. Computing power has an explicit expression without root finding.

Comment: @Josef: You're right, I didn't notice this. Thanks for pointing it out, using solve_power directly if of course much easier. This should be the accepted answer here.

Answer (score 2):

`solve_power` can solve for any one of the variables given the others. Solving for power uses an explicit formula based on non-central t distribution. All others involve rootfinding.

Finding effect size given power, alpha and the number of observations can be done with

```
power_analysis = TTestIndPower()
effect_size = power_analysis.solve_power(effect_size = None, 
                                         power = 0.8, 
                                         alpha = 0.05,
                                         nobs1 = 100)
```

TTestIndPower is for a test comparing 2 independent samples. Sample size is specified by the number of observations in the first sample `nobs1`, and the ratio of sample sizes between the samples `ratio`, which defaults to 1, i.e. equal sample size in both samples.

Comment: Strangely I'm getting "TypeError: solve_power() got an unexpected keyword argument 'nobs'." I did look at the lit and using the code as you say so unsure why..

Comment: see my edit with the correction. It should be `nobs1` and `ratio` in the two sample case. `nobs` applies in one sample case